# Mysql - efetuar um update via db com “set price = price - 5%”

Tags: mysql

Como efetuo um update onde irá diminuir o preço do produto por porcentagem?

> **Exemplo:**
>
> Tabela:
>
> id | produtos
>
> 10 | 1.40

Como faço um update que me retorne o valor 1.40 - 5%?

Answer (score 2):

Cinco por cento = `5 / 100`

portanto:

```
preco = preco - ( preco * 5 / 100 )
```